# Too many log files being created in Temp folder

Tags: windows-8

I am running Windows 8. Suddenly one day I got an error that C:\ is low on disk space. After doing lot of analysis found that every minute 4-5 log files are being written into Temp folder. File name is like "MSI1d567.log". Googled but did not get any answers. How do I stop the errors. Here are the partial contents of the log file:

```
    === Verbose logging started: 4/1/2014  2:50:03  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9200.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorsvw.exe ===
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:779]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:779]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:779]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:779]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:779]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:795]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:795]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (58:34) [02:50:03:795]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (58:40) [02:50:03:795]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
MSI (s) (58:40) [02:50:03:795]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:795]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:795]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:795]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:795]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:795]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: Original package ==> C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall Flags override found.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall VersionNT override found.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall ServicePackLevel override found.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}'.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:810]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\1bd6ba.msp'.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: SequencePatches starts. Product code: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, Product version: 12.0.21005, Upgrade code: {015856DA-C69D-3EE0-85EC-270367A147A1}, Product language 1033
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: {48CD6D20-8F9D-4E10-B0EE-90254A3FCD8E} - 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.1
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.1 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {9163C0D5-3B12-3A44-AC0E-842BFF164176}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.1.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.2
1: 2746 2: RTM.1 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {9163C0D5-3B12-3A44-AC0E-842BFF164176} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.2 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {E6D16FD8-2790-3922-9692-A2C99D4831E8}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.2.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.3
1: 2746 2: RTM.2 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {E6D16FD8-2790-3922-9692-A2C99D4831E8} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.3 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {B0A82E02-E959-3C46-AB11-D38527BC573E}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.3.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.4
1: 2746 2: RTM.3 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {B0A82E02-E959-3C46-AB11-D38527BC573E} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.4 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {C9E7751E-88ED-36CF-B610-71A1D262E906}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.4.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.5
1: 2746 2: RTM.4 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {C9E7751E-88ED-36CF-B610-71A1D262E906} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.5 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {23127FE2-983D-305A-904D-89ED86D36269}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.5.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.6
1: 2746 2: RTM.5 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {23127FE2-983D-305A-904D-89ED86D36269} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.6 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {B4D3393A-68BE-4A5C-B963-93FFE1128E9E}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.6.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.7
1: 2746 2: RTM.6 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {B4D3393A-68BE-4A5C-B963-93FFE1128E9E} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.7 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {B86C786E-11A2-4CAB-BB2E-D7CD5D65D552}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.7.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.8
1: 2746 2: RTM.7 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {B86C786E-11A2-4CAB-BB2E-D7CD5D65D552} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.8 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {B6A0A174-33E0-3D42-92EA-547D318CB149}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.8.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.9
1: 2746 2: RTM.8 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {B6A0A174-33E0-3D42-92EA-547D318CB149} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.9 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {27622297-16B1-35C9-B92B-74238ECCA333}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.9.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.10
1: 2746 2: RTM.9 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {27622297-16B1-35C9-B92B-74238ECCA333} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.10 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {AF42CC8A-A9F5-33B0-8AE2-10E77CEEB4CD}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.10.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.11
1: 2746 2: RTM.10 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {AF42CC8A-A9F5-33B0-8AE2-10E77CEEB4CD} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.11 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {64484316-E4BA-38B3-8954-0358522A8D40}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.11.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.12
1: 2746 2: RTM.11 3: C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi 4: {64484316-E4BA-38B3-8954-0358522A8D40} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} 
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.12 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\1aa7bce.msi. Expected product {2067FDB5-4D1F-39A4-8473-4598420B9AFB}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.12.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.13
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Tables 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Columns 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _sqlAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Property 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Directory 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CreateFolder 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: EventManifest 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Group 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiDigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiLockPermissionsEx 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NetFxNativeImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RegLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveRegistry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceInstall 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UIText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Upgrade 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: User 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UserGroup 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: WixDependencyProvider 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlConfig 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _sqlAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Component 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Feature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Directory 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CreateFolder 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: EventManifest 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: FeatureComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Group 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssemblyName 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiDigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiLockPermissionsEx 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NetFxNativeImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RegLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveRegistry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceInstall 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UIText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Upgrade 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: User 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UserGroup 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: WixDependencyProvider 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlConfig 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Patch 4: CREATE TABLE `Patch` ( `File_` CHAR(72) NOT NULL, `Sequence` INTEGER NOT NULL, `PatchSize` LONG NOT NULL, `Attributes` INTEGER NOT NULL, `Header` OBJECT, `StreamRef_` CHAR(72)  PRIMARY KEY `File_`, `Sequence` ) 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Patch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: 'PatchPackage' table is missing or empty.  No pre-transform fixup necessary.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: Applying regular transform to database.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Tables 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Columns 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _sqlAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Property 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Directory 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CreateFolder 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: EventManifest 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Group 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiDigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiLockPermissionsEx 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NetFxNativeImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RegLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveRegistry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceInstall 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UIText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Upgrade 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: User 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UserGroup 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: WixDependencyProvider 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlConfig 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_PatchCache 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineData 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineCost 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _MsiPatchAuthorTransformView 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _MsiPatchPatchTransformView 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Patch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Detected that this is a 'Small Update' patch.  Any remaining transforms in the patch will be skipped.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: The minimum 'Media.DiskId' value inserted by a patch transform is 100
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: The maximum 'Media.DiskId' value inserted by a patch transform is 99
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: The minimum 'File.Sequence' or 'Patch.Sequence' value inserted by a patch transform is 10000
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: The maximum 'File.Sequence' or 'Patch.Sequence' value inserted by a patch transform is 9999.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: TRANSFORM: Applying special patch transform to database.
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _sqlAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AppSearch 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: BindImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Component 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ProgId 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Feature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Directory 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CreateFolder 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: EventManifest 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: FeatureComponents 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Group 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssemblyName 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiDigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiLockPermissionsEx 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: NetFxNativeImage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RegLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveRegistry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceInstall 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UIText 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Upgrade 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: User 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: UserGroup 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: WixDependencyProvider 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlConfig 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: XmlFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_PatchCache 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineData 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:80) [02:50:03:826]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineCost 3: -2147287038
```

Comment: The first line of the log indicates .NET Framework 4.0 is attempting to be installed which makes no sense since Windows 8.x has 4.5.x installed and an in-place upgrade to 4.0

Comment: I wonder if this is due to either a windows service or something in task scheduler. Does the same issue persist in safe mode?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 also installed.

Comment: The Windows Installer is always running in the taskbar

Comment: See this link (not an answer) http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-windows-installer-always-running/f04022b1-e85e-4452-8f27-fd06403c9dda but as I said, first off, we need to know if this is the cause - the installer won't run in safe mode, so boot into safe mode, leave it 10 minutes and then check if the same issue persists?

Comment: Seen this before, did not help :(

Comment: Sorry, are you refusing to test it in safe mode?

Comment: There were other things running on the system so it was difficult to reboot the system in safe mode.

Comment: From the logs, I was able to figure out the culprit. It was due to Visual Studio 2013. It was not installed correctly. I ran repair on the VS 2013 installer and I have not seen the logs for some time now - about 6 hours. Will keep it under observation for another 24 hours to confirm if the issue is really resolved.

Comment: People, let's try to figure out some common patterns here. In my case, I had VS 2013 Web Edition and VS 2013 Desktop Edition and VS 2013 Win edition installed, and I believe this log cluttering started to occur only after I installed the VS 2013 Community Edition. I also have some editions of VS 2012 installed, and all the related software (IIS Expresses, SQL Expresses, ...). I also had Azure dev kits installed and a lot of other SDKs.

Comment: Additional info: I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials, and also EMET! Every minute (!) approximately 4 files are dumped, each log is about 3.2 MB. It's like a ticking time bomb filling the HDD.

Comment: VS repair seems to solved it for me so far. I lost some gigs though in the process, but now there's no fillup

Comment: Is it safe to delete the logs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the logs I figured out that Visual Studio 2013 was not installed correctly. After running repair from the Visual Studio installer the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 4):

This [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/visual-studio-2013-continuously-repairs-producing-many-small-log-files/) describes the problem and gives the solution. It worked in my case:

> If you have Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate editions installed and are finding many small MSI*.log files in your `%TEMP%` directory, you may find you are running low on disk space because of how many of these files are created. While they may only be about 3MB, what causes these files to be produced can do so often enough that it may not take long to fill up the drive where `%TEMP%` resides.
>
> ### Workaround
>
> We are consistently seeing this issue caused by a missing directory, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC (or `%SystemRoot%`\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC).
>
> To work around this issue,
>
> 1. Open an elevated command prompt.
> 2. Type: `mkdir %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC`
>
> In PowerShell, use `$env:SystemRoot` instead of `%SystemRoot%`.