# How can I disable Windows 7 MSI logging?

Tags: windows-7, logging, temporary-files

I ran CCleaner just now and found that it wanted to free 14 GB from my Windows temp files. I took a look and they are being stored at C:\Windows\Temp, and they are some sort of MSI log file. Google tells me these are installation log files, but everything is about how to enable them, and I can't figure out how to *disable* them. This frequently happens and it sucks up a lot of space on my SSD.

Here's a sampling of the first few lines of the many log files:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 7/19/2014  2:01:13  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorsvw.exe ===
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:729]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:729]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:729]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:729]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:729]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:731]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:731]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (24:F4) [02:01:13:732]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (B4:88) [02:01:13:734]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
MSI (s) (B4:88) [02:01:13:734]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (B4:B8) [02:01:13:735]: Resetting cached policy values
```

There are hundreds of these files with a name like `MSI#####.LOG`, with the # being a letter or number. Even if I delete them they come back a few days or weeks later.

I have tried the solution given [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545723) to disable the logging but it did not work.

How can I turn these off completely?

Comment: I think the reason you're getting a lot of log files is because some MSI-based setup didn't finish properly. The sample you posted reads: `Calling process: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorsvw.exe` The application is described as **.NET Runtime Optimization Service**. A few lines later there's a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) (`{9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}`) which appears to be associated with **Visual Studio Professional 2013**. Related question: [Too many log files being created in Temp folder](http://superuser.com/q/736253/289138)

Comment: @and31415 Interesting, I'll give that solution a try. If it works I invite anyone to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I'll just note I never found a solution for this. It was definitely connected to a bad Visual Studio installation, so the newer community version might not have this issue. But nevertheless I long ago reformatted and installed Windows 10 and do not have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Applications and/or the system should not place anything in that directory for long term storage.  You should have no issue deleting them.

As for the logging, you can delete the registry setting that turns it on.  Go to

```
Local Computer>Software>Policies>Microsoft>Windows>Installer
```

If there is a key of "Logging", delete it (maybe write down the value first).

Now if you are on a domain, the admins may force this setting, so you many not be able to do this.  Also, various applications will continue to dump data into that directory (Office 365, for sure).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Policies>Microsoft>Windows, but there's no Installer. Is this the right place to be looking?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct path.  I see it in my registry. Hmmm...  Maybe you could add it with minimal logging and see if it reduces it?  Add a key "Logging" with the value "mo" and that may reduce the amount logged (only out of disk and out of memory errors).

Comment: The "Installer" key is not there by default, you have to enable it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging