# 1Tb Hard drive showing 30Gb remaining

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm using Windows 7 64 (a Dell i5 box).  I have a 1Tb C: drive with the following partitions:

1. 39MB (OEM Partition)
2. 13.15GB NTFS (Recovery partition)
3. 918.32GB NTFS (Boot Partition)

When I "Select All" in Explorer on C: root (with hidden and system files visible) and choose properties, it shows approximately 270GB used in total.  However Windows tells me only 30GB of my drive is free.  Somewhere I've lost over 600GB.

I did the following:

1. Run chkdsk (everything is OK)
2. Run disk cleanup (recovered around 60GB).

So I'm still down almost half my drive.  How can I find out where the missing space is?

Comment: AFAIK even if you turn on hidden and system files, they still aren't counted  if you look up the combined size using explorer.

Comment: I have been using a great open source tool which travels to all directories and files, calculates their statistics, and represents them graphically sorted by size.  I'm a little new here, and am concerned that my answer might be considered software recommendation.  _(If a moderator can point me somewhere to clarify, I would appreciate it.)_  In the mean time, just know that there are tools for this.

Comment: If you go to "Computer" in Explorer and pull up the properties for the C: drive, it will show a usage pie chart.  What does Windows show for _Used Space_, _Free Space_, and _Capacity_?  We need to make sure that the OS is seeing the drive as the correct size.

Comment: It says Total Size 918GB, Free Space 28.0GB and the Space Used bar is almost full.

Comment: GuitarPicker a software recommendation would be useful, as long as it's free of course.

Comment: Interestingly, WinDirStat hangs at 6%.

Comment: Open cmd.exe and type: `cd C:\` and then `dir /a`. Paste the result here. The "/a" switch means all. Try "dir" with and without it and you will see a difference.

Comment: Check Disk Management if there is any un-partioned space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much messing about, I managed to find the answer.  The trick was to run WinDirStat as Administrator.  When you do that the missing files magically appear.  In my case they were all in Windows/Temp.

On closer inspection it turns out that a particular installer writes a 3mb log file every time it fails, before trying (and failing) again.  I had over 200,000 of these files in Windows/Temp.  The cultprit was a program with id {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, which I believe is Visual Studio 2010 or 2013. Repairing VS solves the problem.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/736253/too-many-log-files-being-created-in-temp-folder